# When assign an new observation to existing KMEAN model, how to standardized an new observation?

Tags: machine-learning, k-means

I just performed a Kmean clustering model using this process.

1. Collect data (100 obs).
2. Standardized it based on mean/SD of 100 observation.
3. Perform model and save it in Pickle file.

The question is

If i have new observation (50 new obs) and i want to
know which group does the new data belong to based on existing centroid,
which mean/SD should i use for standardized the new observation?

1. mean/SD of of old data (100 obs)
2. mean/SD of of new data (50 new obs)
3. mean/SD of of all data (150 obs)

Thank you

tried all the 3 method but idk which method are right.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts : training and inference.  Inference is based on trained model. So you should take 1st choice . Mean and SD of 100 obs.